# Send back data from activerecord model on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I was wondering if there was a way that i can send back data from a model on create. In my app i have a Model that that on create generates keys and then hashes them in the database. I would like to get the unhashed form of the key and send it back to the user and allow them to view it only once and have them save it elsewhere. I tried setting a flash message from inside the model but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add non-persisted fields to models my using `attr_accessor` just like a regular ruby class. ActiveRecord won't pick up on these. So you can just add a field and put it there, and they will be present for the life of that object (or until cleared). Just don't do a `reload`.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can see is to:

1. after_initialize you assing key to additional `attr_accessor` (let's call it `unhashed_key`)
2. add `before_validation on: :create` that will take `unhashed_key`, hash it and assign to `hashed_key`
3. On save only `hashed_key` goes to db and `unhashed_key` is still available for reading
4. You pass `unhashed_key` through flash or session for next request (I don't think flash is the best way, use session maybe)